# Check the render method of `RestApi`

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

i got this This error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `RestApi`.

This is my code App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RestApi from './x/RestApi';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <RestApi/>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
})
```

This is my code RestApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button, Flatlist, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default function RestApi() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [value,setValue] = useState("");
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [button, setButton] = useState("Simpan");
    const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({});

    const submit =()=>{
        const data = {
            value,title
        }
        //console.log(data)
        if(button=="Simpan"){
            axios.post('https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news', data)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log('res: ', res)
                setTitle("")
                setValue("")
                GetData()
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log('error: ',err)
            })
            }else{
                axios.put(`https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news/${selectedUser.id}`, data)
                .then(res=>{
                    console.log('res: ',res)
                    setTitle("")
                    setValue("")
                    GetData()
                    setButton("Simpan")
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log('error: ', err)
                })
            }
        }
        const onSelectItem = (item)=>{
            console.log(item)
            setSelectedUser(item)
            setTitle(item.title)
            setValue(item.value)
            setButton("Update")
        }

        const GetData=()=>{
            axios.get('https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news')
            .then(res=>{
                const data1 = (res.data.data)
                console.log('res: ', data1)
                setItems(data1)
            })
        }
        const onDelete=(item)=>{
            axios.delete(`https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news/${item.id}`)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log('res: ', res)
                GetData()
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log('error: ', err)
            })
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            GetData()
        }, [])

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Tampilkan Api (CRUD)</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content1}>
                    <Text>Post Data</Text>

                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Masukan judul berita"
                        style={styles.input}
                        value={title}
                        onChangeText={(value)=>setTitle(value)}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Masukan Isi berita"
                        style={styles.input}
                        value={value}
                        onChangeText={(value)=>setValue(value)}
                    />
                <Button
                title={button}
                onPress={submit}
                />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.content1}>
                    <Text>Get Data Berita</Text>
                    
                    <Flatlist
                        data={items}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
                        renderItem={({item})=>{
                            return (
                                <View>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>onDelete(item)}>
                                <Text style={{color: 'red', alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>X</Text>    
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>onSelectItem(item)}style={{borderRadius: 6,backgroundColor:'grey', padding: 5, marginBottom:10}}>
                                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.title}</Text>
                                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.value}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>    
                            )
                        }}
                    />



                </View>
            </View>
        )
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            flex:1,
            backgroundColor:'white'
        },
        header:{
            paddingTop: 50,
            paddingHorizontal: 16,
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            alignItems: 'center'
        },
        title:{
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 20
        },
        content1:{
            paddingHorizontal: 16
        },
        input:{
            borderWidth:1,
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 5,
            borderRadius: 6,
            marginTop: 10
        },
        contentNews:{
            backgroundColor:'grey',
            paddingVertical:10
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RestApi component does return anything, because the return statement is nested within the submit function, but that does not get called.

Could you try unnesting the return statement? See example below, where I also unnested the useEffect call and several other functions.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
Button,
Flatlist,
SafeAreaView,
ScrollView,
StyleSheet,
Text,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
View
} from 'react-native'

export default function RestApi() {
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [button, setButton] = useState('Simpan')
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({})

const submit = () => {
    const data = {
        value,
        title
    }
    //console.log(data)
    if (button == 'Simpan') {
        axios
            .post('https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news', data)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('res: ', res)
                setTitle('')
                setValue('')
                GetData()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error: ', err)
            })
    } else {
        axios
            .put(
                `https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news/${selectedUser.id}`,
                data
            )
            .then(res => {
                console.log('res: ', res)
                setTitle('')
                setValue('')
                GetData()
                setButton('Simpan')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error: ', err)
            })
    }
}

const onSelectItem = item => {
    console.log(item)
    setSelectedUser(item)
    setTitle(item.title)
    setValue(item.value)
    setButton('Update')
}

const GetData = () => {
    axios
        .get('https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news')
        .then(res => {
            const data1 = res.data.data
            console.log('res: ', data1)
            setItems(data1)
        })
}
const onDelete = item => {
    axios
        .delete(
            `https://achmadhilmy-sanbercode.my.id/api/v1/news/${item.id}`
        )
        .then(res => {
            console.log('res: ', res)
            GetData()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err)
        })
}

useEffect(() => {
    GetData()
}, [])

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Tampilkan Api (CRUD)</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content1}>
            <Text>Post Data</Text>

            <TextInput
                placeholder="Masukan judul berita"
                style={styles.input}
                value={title}
                onChangeText={value => setTitle(value)}
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Masukan Isi berita"
                style={styles.input}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={value => setValue(value)}
            />
            <Button title={button} onPress={submit} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.content1}>
            <Text>Get Data Berita</Text>

            <Flatlist
                data={items}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => onDelete(item)}>
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        color: 'red',
                                        alignSelf: 'flex-end'
                                    }}>
                                    X
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => onSelectItem(item)}
                                style={{
                                    borderRadius: 6,
                                    backgroundColor: 'grey',
                                    padding: 5,
                                    marginBottom: 10
                                }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                                    {item.value}
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
},
header: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20
},
content1: {
    paddingHorizontal: 16
},
input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginTop: 10
},
contentNews: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    paddingVertical: 10
}
})
```